# how to query aws target group by its tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

how to query aws target group by its tags

I tried this but not working

```
aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --query "TargetGroups[?Tags[?Key=='env' && Value=='test']]"
```

Comment: What is the output or action you are expecting as a result of this command? Are you wanting to filter the list so that it only shows Target Groups that have a Tag of `{Key:env, Value:test}`? If so, that would require a `--filter` instead of a `--query`. Please tell us more about what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for your response. Yes, I want to filter the target group having `{Key:env, Value:test}`

Comment: I imagine you'd use something like `aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --filters "Name=tag:env,Values=test"` You can then use `--query` to control which fields you want to appear in the response.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It seems `--filters` option is not available on `describe-target-groups`

Comment: I found workaround solution
`aws elbv2 describe-target-groups | jq -r '.TargetGroups[].TargetGroupArn' | xargs -I {} aws elbv2 describe-tags --resource-arns {} --query "TagDescriptions[?Tags[?Key=='env' && Value=='$env'] && Tags[?Key=='service_name' &&Value=='$service_name']].ResourceArn" --output text`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I don't know if it is an ideal one.

```bash
aws elbv2 describe-target-groups | jq -r '.TargetGroups[].TargetGroupArn' | xargs -I {} aws elbv2 describe-tags --resource-arns {} --query "TagDescriptions[?Tags[?Key=='env' && Value=='$env'] && Tags[?Key=='service_name' && Value=='$service_name']].ResourceArn" --output text
```